# How to schedule a new method in a Spring enabled web app at runtime?

Tags: java, spring

Right now I have one bean with a @Scheduled method working fine; it's declared in my applicationContext.xml.

```
<!-- some JPA stuff -->

<bean id="aWorkingBean" class="some.package.WorkingBean">
    <property name="someDAO" ref="someDAO" />
</bean>

<task:annotation-driven scheduler="myScheduler" />
<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="10" />
```

What I'm trying to do is programmatically schedule another method (e.g. loading some annotated class and inject its dependencies) upon request. Something like:

```
WebApplicationContext ctx = ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();
BeanDefinitionBuilder builder = BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(NonWorkingBean.class);
// add DAO references...
ctx.registerBeanDefinition("nonWorkingBean", builder.getBeanDefinition()); // <-- this doesn't work
```

Obviously it doesn't work because the XmlWebApplicationContext is read-only and has no *registerBeanDefinition* method. Is there any other way to achieve this?

I'm using Tomcat 6.0.29 and Spring 3.0.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<task:scheduler>` and `@Scheduled` is really just a convenience approach to scheduling static tasks. It's not really suitable for dynamic scheduling. Yes, you can make it work, but it's going to be awkward.

When you put `<task:scheduler id="myScheduler">` into your config, Spring creates a `TaskScheduler` bean called `myScheduler`. This can be injected into your own beans, and can be invoked programmatically in order to schedule new tasks. You'll need to create a `Runnable` to pass to the `TaskScheduler`, but that should be simple enough.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I managed to schedule new tasks by getting the myScheduler bean and using Runnable, like you just said, but I was wondering whether it's safe to to that regarding a) the transactions and b) thread leaks. (My scheduled method makes use of some DAOs).

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that, but you would usually use an `AutowireCapableBeanFactory`.

Here's one way to do it:

```
final WebApplicationContext ctx =
    ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();

// create the object yourself
// and inject the dependenices you want manually
final Object existingBean = initializeYourObjectHere();

AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory = ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();

// now autowire it, injecting the remaining dependencies
beanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(
    existingBean, AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE, true);

// run post processors and register bean under this name
beanFactory.initializeBean(existingBean, "newBeanName");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I have another question: if the the existingBean has a @Scheduled method, is it supposed to be automatically scheduled?  Also, after initializing the bean, when I call ctx.getBean("newBeanName") is throwing NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Comment: a) if the post processor for @Scheduled is registered, yes. b) you might need to refresh the context first

Comment: Sorry, although your suggestion is very good, I'm still stuck with this: a) regarding the post processor, isn't the <task:annotation-driven scheduler="myScheduler" /> enough? b) is it safe to refresh the context even though I have the JPA stuff?